Sci-fi movie with a group of people trying to fix an old spaceship
The movie in question is early or mid 90's, I think. I saw it long ago on TV and it was live-action.
A group of people are trying to fix an old battleship; the battleship was a spaceship, the last of its kind, because humans lost the war or something. I think the old guy was crew there and they ask for help from some aliens they call engineers or some such, but it turns out they are the bad guys and their homeworld is a machine they built. They want the old guy's daughter to assimilate with their blob of flesh for brains, because she is special or something.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where did you see this?  (Theatre or TV, country)  Was it animated or live-action?

Are we talking about a seafaring battleship here or a spaceship?

Helloo!  i failed with that info >_<  i saw it on a tv and live action. it was a sci fi and the battleship was a spaceship. last of it's kind cause humans lost the war or something, saw it once and long ago XD

@Demask1nos please update the question ... do not write comments

This is The Osiris Chronicles (1998), AKA The Warlord: Battle for the Galaxy, a feature-length pilot for a series that never materialised.

In the future, galactic civil war destroys the human space civilization and a new Dark Age begins. On a distant planet, a scavenger looking for his abducted sister teams up with a former general who wishes to rebuild the Galactic Republic.


As noted above, the story is set in a future dark age, after humanity rose to establish a Galactic Republic, then fell into decline due to in-fighting.
The protagonist, Justin Thorpe, is a scavenger and trader living on a planet named Caliban 5 with his little sister, Nova, under the rule of a warlord named Xian. After learning that Nova has been taken off-world by an unknown party, he's introduced to a former General of the Republic, Alexander Sorenson, by the General's granddaughter and Nova's best friend, Maggie. The General offers Thorpe the use of a derelict Republic warship, the Osiris, in order to pursue Nova's abductors, but first they need the help of mysterious aliens known as the Engineers to get the ship's tachyon generators back online.
They subsequently discover that the Engineers are the ones who took Nova. The Engineers no longer reproduce by conventional means, and instead seek out gifted children from other species to re-educate and incorporate into their society. Their homeworld is a rogue planet masked by cloaking technology, and their highest authority is the Sublime Plenum, a pulsating mass of organic tissue containing the minds of their greatest, deceased citizens. According to the Engineers, Nova is the most gifted child they've found in years, and will likely be incorporated into the Plenum one day.



